# find similarity between two text strings..?

Tags: c, perl

Suppose I have an interface for entering two strings, and then to check that they are similar to each other or not.

Like.

String1:

```
Manufacture & Exporter Of Sequins, Silk Taffeta, Cotton, Fabric, Woven Sequins, Woven Sequin Garments etc.
```

String2:

```
Manufacture Silk Taffeta, Cotton, Fabric, Woven Sequins, Woven Sequin Garments , healthy soups etc.
```

are similar to each other.

Comment: There are a lot of standard algorithms for calculating string similarity.

Comment: Your Qn already has 4 close votes. So, I think you need to clearly describe your problem. `similarity` is a very braod term.

Answer (score 2):

You should search for fuzzy string comparison, or [Approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching).